# How to evaluate $\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{k^2}{n^2 + k^2}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How can I evaluate $\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{k^2}{n^2 + k^2}$? I tried integrating $\lim_{n\to \infty}\int_1^n \frac{k^2}{n^2 + k^2}dk$ but didn't get a finite answer. How to do this?

I know the answer is less than $\pi/4$ because the sum is less than the area under $1/(1+x^2)$ from $1$ to infinity.

Comment: The limit as written is $+\infty$. For $k \geqslant n/2$, the term is $\geqslant 1/5$, so the sum $> n/10$.

Comment: @DanielFischer The sum diverges? I calculate it's less than $\pi/4$ by comparing with graph of $1/(1+x^2)$.

Comment: Yes. Maybe the term should have been $\dfrac{n}{n^2+k^2}$? Or $\dfrac{k^2}{n(n^2+k^2)}$?

Comment: @DanielFischer If it is what I have written we can write it as $\lim_{n\to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^n 1/(( n/k)^2 + 1)$. That is less than area under graph from $1$ to infty of $1/(1+x^2)$

Comment: No, for $k \geqslant n/2$, the term in the sum is $\geqslant \dfrac{1}{2^2+1}$.

Comment: Ok what if it's $n/(n^2 + k^2)$?

Comment: Then it's a Riemann sum for $$\int_0^1 \frac{1}{1+x^2}\,dx = \frac{\pi}{4}.$$

Comment: Right and if inside it's $k/(n^2 + k^2)$, it's riemann sum for $x/(1+x^2)$?

Comment: Correct, $$\frac{k}{n^2+k^2} = \frac{1}{n}\cdot \frac{\frac{k}{n}}{1+\left(\frac{k}{n}\right)^2}.$$

Comment: Thanks Mr. Fischer. So I was right in beginning when I didn't get finite answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If we denote 
$$S_n=\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{k^2}{n^2 + k^2}=\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{\left(\frac kn\right)^2}{1 + \left(\frac kn\right)^2}$$
then we see that $\frac{S_n}{n}$ is a Riemann sum and 
$$\frac{S_n}{n}\to\int_0^1\frac{x^2}{1+x^2}dx=1-\int_0^1\frac{1}{1+x^2}dx=1-\arctan1=1-\frac\pi 4$$
It's clear that $\lim_n S_n=+\infty$.

Comment: Nicely Done Sami.